# Electron create actual mouse click in operating system

Tags: javascript, electron

I am creating an electron app that acts as an overlay to another app.

Sometimes parts of my interface are not visible but the electron `BrowserWindow` is still taking up space (I want to avoid dynamically resizing the `BrowserWindow`).

When somebody clicks on an invisible part of my overlay I close the interface entirely, here's the code that accomplishes that:

```js
main.js:

const { BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')

// Win is an instance of BrowserWindow
ipcMain.on('closeWindow', () => { if (win != null) win.close() })



renderer.js:

const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

let invisibleElem = document.getElementById('invisbleElement')

/* invisibleElem is made invisible by setting opacity to 0 to ensure this
   event listener actually triggers                                       */
invisibleElem.addEventListener('mousedown', () => { 
  ipcRenderer.send('closeWindow')
})
```

After my window is closed by `win.close()` in `main.js` I want to immideately make the operating system trigger a mouse click again at the current cursor position. This will ensure the user experience is like my overlay wasn't actually there at all (because from the user's perspective, it wasn't).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You might be interested in [RobotJS](http://robotjs.io/)

Comment: That looks like a good solution. Do you know how it can be integrated into [electron-forge](https://www.electronforge.io/)'s build system?

Comment: I haven't worked with electron-forge, especially with the new major version they released recently. However, electron (correctly set-up) usually has no trouble using Node modules in the renderer process. I even had a native node module (using the N-API) working in the renderer, so I don't think you will have any big issue.

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is RobotJS needs to download a binary for your particular operating system. When it comes time to publish my app for multiple operating systems electron-forge will need to be instructed to include the correct binary for each operating system.

Comment: What you can do is download the `.node` release for each platform, dynamically import the correct one using `process.platform`, then call the methods directly.

Answer (score 0):

robotjs is node library that can control and create mouse clicks. Setup and release is not as trivial as jsut adding a package thought